# Percentage based layouts in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Coming from an Android background I'm used to using `ConstraintLayout` to define percentage based margins and sizes for my UI. I was wondering if there is a widget in Flutter that can achieve something similar. I've been looking at the widget [documentation](https://flutter.io/widgets/layout/) but I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In flutter, percentage sizes are represented using `FractionalOffset` which is basically 0 < {x,y} < 1 coordinates

There are a few widgets available using this logic, like:

- [FractionallySizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html)
- [Align](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html)

These, combined with a stack should allow about any layout you need without using `LayoutBuilder` or similar.